# Sorting an object based on a property of a child object

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I have an object, say for example, a "car" object.  Inside this car object I have another object of "tires."   This tires object has a few properties, one of them being manufacturer.

I need to sort an array of cars based on the tire manufacturer.

I know how to sort the cars object based on a property inside the car object with descriptors.  But how do you sort based on a property inside the tires object?

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sort descriptors use KVC, so you can sort based on the tire manufacturer property with dot syntax. Something like:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"tires.manufacturer" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortedArray = [cars sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];
```

For more on KVC check here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html

Comment: ah i see.  i didn't realize dot syntax was valid.  well that makes things simple

Comment: well, which tire do you want to sort on? the easiest solution here would be to add a getter `-(NSString *)manufacturer` on the tires, and return whichever one is the one you want to sort on.

Comment: currently all tires are the same so just grabbing the first would be sufficient.  i just dont know how to get around the syntax of the child object being an array or nsset property.  nothing i have done has worked for getting ANY of the objects in the set.  the layout is a car object with a tires array of tire objects.

Comment: Using KVC with nested arrays and collection operators seems impossible to me because `NSArray` has a special implementation of `valueForKey`.